# Parser or export for slow queries table (mysql.slow_log) on AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

So I turned on slow query logging in my Amazon RDS instance (via the method [here](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#14)), and now I'm wondering how to parse the data collected in the slow queries table (mysql.slow_log). Can I use the mysqlslowdump command?

If not, are there ways of exporting the table to the slow log file format that mysqlslowdump creates?

What, if any, other parsers can I use to parse the data in the slow queries table?

**EDIT:** Found a python script that dumps the slow_log table to a format readable by mysqldumpslow command (thanks memonic). I modified it, which you can see here:
https://gist.github.com/1484489

Answer (score 0):

I've tested Percona's tools and they are great

this one [pt-query-advisor](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-advisor.html) Analyze queries and advise on possible problems, and this one [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-digest.html) converts slow log into more readable format. :)